# In XCEED wpf propertygrid the setter for bool is never called (F#)

Tags: wpf, f#, propertygrid, xceed

I have the following value

```
let mutable enMarker = if serie.MarkerSize > 0.0 then true else false
```

that is a Boolean and the following member that sets that value

```
member x.``Enable/disable marker`` with get() = enMarker
                                   and set v  = enMarker <- v
                                                if v = false then this.``Marker size`` <- 0 |> uint32
                                                else serie.MarkerSize <- this.``Marker size`` |> float
```

My problem is that the setter of the member is not called when I check the checkbox of the propertyGrid. Am I missing something here?

Comment: How you bind to that member? Is binding in two ways mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found it, in case it helps someone the member name was the problem. Changed

```
member x.``Enable/disable marker``
```

to

```
member x.EnableMarker
```

and it was able to call the setter also